# Saved joints from kinect skeleton track

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I work with the kinect. My goal is to store the values ​​gives me the kinect for the location of the body (head,hand etc). I have written some code but I can not understand what values ​​should save and how.I want to store in the db or in a txt file the position of the head,hands and foots.I want the data to understand the movements of the person who stand in front of kinect.For example if someone move her hand the kinect will sent a value.I must store it and understand and to understand the move taken.Sorry for the few info

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace KinectSkeletonApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //Instantiate the Kinect runtime. Required to initialize the device.
        //IMPORTANT NOTE: You can pass the device ID here, in case more than one Kinect device is connected.
        KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
        byte[] pixelData;
        Skeleton[] skeletons;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ///////////////////////////////////


            ///////////////////////////////


            //Runtime initialization is handled when the window is opened. When the window
            //is closed, the runtime MUST be unitialized.
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
            this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Unloaded);

            sensor.ColorStream.Enable();
            sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
        }

        void runtime_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            bool receivedData = false;

            using (SkeletonFrame SFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (SFrame == null)
                {
                    // The image processing took too long. More than 2 frames behind.
                }
                else
                {
                    skeletons = new Skeleton[SFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    SFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
                    receivedData = true;
                }
            }

            if (receivedData)
            {

                Skeleton currentSkeleton = (from s in skeletons
                                            where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                                            select s).FirstOrDefault();

                if (currentSkeleton != null)
                {
                    SetEllipsePosition(head, currentSkeleton.Joints[JointType.Head]);
                    SetEllipsePosition(leftHand, currentSkeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft]);
                    SetEllipsePosition(rightHand, currentSkeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight]);
                    SetEllipsePosition(shoulder_center, currentSkeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter]);

                }
            }
        }


        //This method is used to position the ellipses on the canvas
        //according to correct movements of the tracked joints.

        //IMPORTANT NOTE: Code for vector scaling was imported from the Coding4Fun Kinect Toolkit
        //available here: http://c4fkinect.codeplex.com/
        //I only used this part to avoid adding an extra reference.
        private void SetEllipsePosition(Ellipse ellipse, Joint joint)
        {
            Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonPoint vector = new Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonPoint();
            vector.X = ScaleVector(640, joint.Position.X);
            vector.Y = ScaleVector(480, -joint.Position.Y);
            vector.Z = joint.Position.Z;

            Joint updatedJoint = new Joint();
            updatedJoint = joint;





            updatedJoint.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.Tracked;
            updatedJoint.Position = vector;

            Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, updatedJoint.Position.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, updatedJoint.Position.Y);
        }

        private float ScaleVector(int length, float position)
        {
            float value = (((((float)length) / 1f) / 2f) * position) + (length / 2);
            if (value > length)
            {
                return (float)length;
            }
            if (value < 0f)
            {
                return 0f;
            }

            string r = Convert.ToString(value);

            string path = @"C:\Test\MyTest.txt";
            // This text is added only once to the file. 
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create a file to write to. 
                string createText = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine;
                File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
            }

            // This text is always added, making the file longer over time 
            // if it is not deleted. 
            //string appendText = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine;
            File.AppendAllText(path, r);

            // Open the file to read from. 
            string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);


            return value;
        }

        void MainWindow_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            sensor.Stop();
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += runtime_SkeletonFrameReady;
            sensor.ColorFrameReady += runtime_VideoFrameReady;
            sensor.Start();
        }

        void runtime_VideoFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            bool receivedData = false;

            using (ColorImageFrame CFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {
                if (CFrame == null)
                {
                    // The image processing took too long. More than 2 frames behind.
                }
                else
                {
                    pixelData = new byte[CFrame.PixelDataLength];
                    CFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
                    receivedData = true;
                }
            }

            if (receivedData)
            {
                BitmapSource source = BitmapSource.Create(640, 480, 96, 96,
                        PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixelData, 640 * 4);

                videoImage.Source = source;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail exactly what you're trying to accomplish rather than giving us a code dump and expecting us to interpret what you need help with.  What you need to store will greatly depend on what you want to do with the data

Comment: I want to store in the db or in a txt file the position of the head,hands and foots.I want the data to understand the movements of the person who stand in front of kinect.For example if someone move her hand the kinect will sent a value.I must store it and understand and to understand the move taken.Sorry for the few info.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is getting the X, Y, Z coordiantes for certain Joints?
In this case add this code:

```
Vector3D ShoulderCenter = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].Position.Z);
            Vector3D RightShoulder = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.Z);
            Vector3D LeftShoulder = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.Z);
            Vector3D RightElbow = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.Z);
            Vector3D LeftElbow = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Z);
            Vector3D RightWrist = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position.Z);
            Vector3D LeftWrist = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position.Z);
```

This only defines the Vectors for the upper Body part as you can see. Just add the missing joints the way I did it. 
You need following assemblies:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Fusion;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
```